# List of craftable alchemy potions

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There's still a lot of ingredients I have yet to find any use for, and would like to know what I can craft with them.

So, is there a list available of what kind of potions I can craft, and which ingredients are necessary to craft the specific potions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three general places to look:

- [The Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemy_%28Skyrim%29): pretty decent, lots of links, but likely not complete yet.
- [The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy): generally more rigorous than Wikia, looks to be fairly complete, but usually isn't definitive until the Creation Kit comes out.
- [Prima's Strategy Guide](http://www.primagames.com/games/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/primaguides): This is complete (I have the guide to confirm that), but of course it costs money to access.

Answer (score 6):

Try these:

Sorted by ingredient:
    http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ingredients

Sorted by effect:
    http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects

Answer (score 4):

You could also try the [Skyrim Alchemist Tool](http://skyrim.warlore.org).  It has the same data as the UESP wiki but it can match ingredients by their common effects or show which ingredients have a specific effect.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [potion "calculator"](http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html) which you can use to see the result of combining various ingredients.

Comment: This one is great, I've made heavy use of it.  Thanks.