# Help me find a good potions calculator?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Trying to find a good potions calculator. I used to have one but lost it when my comp crashed, it had a list of the reagents and you input the number you had and it gave a readout of craftable potions. Can someone identify it for me?

Comment: The answers here, which include potions calculator software, might be able to help: [List of craftable alchemy potions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36648/4797).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://arrington.me/alch/) is simple online calculator for your potions,[this one](http://www.garralab.com/skyrim/alchemy.php) is similar with a bit more options.

[This](http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html) one is made around potion profitability.

If you don't like guessing [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Potion_Recipes) you have the list of craftable potions and poisons.